# show the effect of favorite questions more effectively

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

It took me a year of membership and 9000 points rep to learn that you are notified about new answers if you make a question a favorite. And I learnt it just by chance: Someone mentioned that in a comment.

I am sure that is explained somewhere. I didn't look that up now because it doesn't have any effect on my history here.

I suggest modifying the fly-over help for the favorite button. It should not just tell that this make the question a favorite but that you are notified about new answers. I consider that an easy and probably effective change.

Comment: I was not aware of this.

Comment: no, it doesn't notify. but notification will be implemented "sometime in the future"

Comment: This is the most important reason I favorite questions... monitoring.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) and [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2730/22222).